# Gmail wronlgy classifies invoices/purchase emails

Tags: gmail, spam, google-schemas

we sell software licenses but our emails end in the gmail Promotions tab of the main Inbox or even in the spam folder. During the purchase process we send one email with login details, another email with a link to download the invoice and finally another email with an attachment containing the license. Also on every new release, more or less every six months, we send an email notifying users about free upgrade to the new version. We have some complains from gmail users about not having received the license because they didn't notice the email was classified as a promotion or spam. All emails come dkim signed, from spf authorized servers, we are even on the main postmaster feedback loops and in several dns whitelists.

Is there any way to have gmail correctly classify this emails ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on bulk emails. My suggestions are based as my experiences as active Gmail consumer and experiences with learning algorithms

**(1) Avoid being labeled spam:**
 
Request/Advice users to add your Id into their contact list. 
 
Follow the *GMail Bulk Mail Guidelines* [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en).
Apart from DKIM/SPF do you handle abuse, unsubscribe emails? 
If a user marks you spam, nobody can help. Your emails are annoying to user and Gmail will honor user's preference.

**(2) Make it to Primary Tab in Gmail Inbox:**
 
Categories in the INBOX are filtered based on Gmail learning algorithm about user preference. 
Play with keywords in your mail. If Gmail identifies email content to be important, they'll put it in Primary. I noticed emails from *Godaddy.com* with expiration/renewal/promo/profile complete request etc always make it to my Primary tab. Either they have figured it out or could be I have replied to them couple of time. Or I may have spend above threshold time staring at content of their emails.
 
You may request user to mark Star and Important. GMail learning algorithm should pick it. 
 
Usually nobody replies emails in Promotion and Social tabs. Have your user reply your email. Not the best idea I know.

Noticed another ‘major’ retails emails practice : 
For Order confirmation they used retailer@accounts.retailer.com : GMail classified Primary 
For Reminders, Upgrade and feedback they used retailer@value.retailer.com : GMail classified Promotions
For Pure promotion they have yet another email ID dealnews@promo.retailer.com : GMail classified Promotions 
If user is really annoyed with hundreds of promo email, GMAIL learning algorithm may classify promos to go into spam first than value emails. Three ID strategy seems promising.
Good luck !